# Call the same file from the same browser

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that takes aroud 20 seconds to execute and I'm also using sessions inside it.
Code could be simplified as:
file1.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 session_write_close();
 sleep(20);
 echo "I'm the first request";
 ?>
```

file2.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 session_write_close();
 sleep(20);
 echo "I'm the second request";
 ?>
```

Then, when i call file1.php and immediately call file2.php this work as I expected. So I don't have to wait first scritp to finish for sencond to start execution.

But, If I call file1.php and immediately in another tab call file1.php (Yes, the same file) the second request wait until first request has finished and then this begin. This is what i need, call multiple times the same file when previous request are also being processed. What can I do to solve this issue?

**Note:** All of this have to be done from the same web browser.

Comment: Based on your technical skill, check out jQuery's AJAX :)

Comment: I think you should fire the scripts from within an index.php file instead of manually make them load from browser tabs.

Comment: The behaviour depends on the browser, wether it waits for something or not. If you want further requests to a script "blocked" until the first request finished, you'd have to put up a variable in memcached or database or file and simply `exit;` if it is already running. Maybe you should tell the reason behind your aim?

Comment: It's also not clear what you need, "This work as I expected. I don't have to wait first script to finish for second to start" but on the other hand "The second request wait until the first request has finished ... this is what I need"

Comment: The reason is tha I have a php file that handle all request to the website. But, some request may take around 20 seconds, because have to make some exec("nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24 192.168.1.0/24");

Comment: No, it's not AJAX, this is a simple browser request from different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any problems requesting same file multiple times from different tabs. The code you show won't have any problem executing in parallel.

The problem is probably because you try to access same resource simultaneously and this resource is locked by first access, so second access will need to wait until resource is unlocked.

It will be easier to say for sure if you give more information about your actual code.

Comment: Yes, the problem can be a locked resource by the first request. But it is only occurs from the same browser. Chrome, Firefox or IE. Note that I'm ussing session_write_close(); to prevent waiting for write on $_SESSION at the end of execution. Then, I don't Know why?

Comment: Yes, I saw `session_write_close()`, so this shouldn't be because of session locking, unless you use custom session storage function, which may have different locking mechanism...
Or maybe there are some other locks that you may be waiting for?
Hard to say without more information about your code

Comment: Right Now I'm making tests only with the posted code.

Comment: I just made test with your posted code.
Both files execute in parallel (you can measure execution time to validate).
If you see that in the posted code your second request instead of executing 20 seconds, executes about 40 seconds (which means it waits for first request to complete), you probably have some custom sessions mechanism configured, which doesn't correctly release locks when session is closed.

Comment: Yes, if you open the two files, this work. But if you execute the same file twice or more, in different tabs, this have to wait for all the previous requests until end. I'll research something more about sessions in PHP. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similiar with a webservice
- A) it was sure that the answer wasn't there for the first X (i think it was 2 or 3) seconds. So we started wit a sleep.
- B) Do a loop with a limit and check if we have a exception, if so continue the loop, but sleep for X seconds first, do that X amount of times. If it's not working break eventually if the limit is reached.

```
$done_retry  = 0;
$max_retry = 6;
$sleep = 3;
// Start with a sleep, because it's sure the webservice doesn't have the payment
// data yet.
sleep($sleep);

// Do loop to try to grab data from soap.
do {
  try {
    $output = $epc_soap->findPayment($arguments);
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    if ($done_retry < $max_retry) {
      sleep($sleep);
      $done_retry++;
      continue;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  break;
} while (TRUE);
```

It's been a while, so not sure how this still works out, at this time, i think i would preffer looking at React http://reactphp.org/